# Storm-zookeeper transactional logs extremlly large

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm using a ZooKeeper cluster (3 mchines) for my Storm cluster (4 machines). The problem is that -because of the topologies deployed on the storm cluster- the zookeeper transactional logs grow to be extremly large making the zookeeper desk to be full and what is really strange that those logs are not devided into multiple files instead I'm having one big transactional file in every zookeeper machine! making the autopurge in my zookeeper configuration not to have any affect on those files.

Is there a way to solve this problem from zookeeper side, or can I change the way storm uses zookeeper to minimize the size of those logs?
Note: I'm using zookeeper 3.6.4 and Storm 0.9.6 .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by using Pacemarker to process heartbeats from workers instead of zookeeper; That allowed me to avoid writting to zookeeper disk in order to maintain consistency and use in-memory store instead. In order to be able to use Pacemaker I upgraded to Storm-1.0.2.